# Switch from a View (Login) to another View with a TabBarController

Tags: iphone, sdk, view, switching, tabbarcontroller

i'm new at IPhone SDK Developing and now i need some help.

I have a LoginView where the User have to authentificate his legitimacy.
After he enter his Username and Passwort he click on the "Sign In" Button.

Then i want to load my "Real-App". Here is the Problem because i can't switch from the LoginScreen to the TabBarController. I found many solutions but only for switching to other views.

Is there a way to do it  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the LoginView using

```
[loginViewController.view removeFromSuperView];
```

Then add the TabBar with

```
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

Comment: yeah thats nice. But "[loginViewController.view removeFromSuperView];" gives a Warning and when I click on my TableView in the TabBarController i can see the LoginMenu in the Background.
(I use FlipAnimation in the TableView)

Comment: What does the warning say? And when do you use a FlipAnimation?